# mysql return all rows whether data exists or not

Tags: mysql, rdbms

Here is a part of table from which I am retrieving data for the last 3 months including current month

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
| Wo_id       | updated_at            | 
+-------------+-----------------------+
|           1 | 2018-12-05 10:38:06   |
|           2 | 2018-12-02 15:21:17   |
|           3 | 2018-12-01 22:18:53   |
|           4 | 2018-10-25 10:38:06   |
|           5 | 2018-10-18 15:21:17   |
|           6 | 2018-10-16 22:18:53   |
|           7 | 2018-10-19 10:26:19   |
|           8 | 2018-10-27 07:06:52   |
|           9 | 2018-09-25 11:35:09   |
|          10 | 2018-09-18 12:54:27   |
```

The query I tried is

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(updated_at) month,YEAR(updated_at) year_name, 
MONTH(updated_at) month_no, COUNT(*) work_orders 
FROM work_orders where updated_at >= last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 3 month 
GROUP by MONTH(updated_at),YEAR(updated_at) 
ORDER BY MONTH(updated_at) DESC
```

The Output I am getting is

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| month       | year_name   | month_no | work_orders |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| December    |      2018   | 12       |      3      |
| October     |      2018   | 10       |      5      |
| September   |      2018   | 9        |      2      |
```

As you can see the query is neglecting November as its data is not in the table. It is Including `September` in order to complete the cycle of 3 months which is wrong. I want the output like this

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| month       | year_name   | month_no | work_orders |
+-------------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| December    |      2018   | 12       |      3      |
| November    |      2018   | 9        |      0      |
| October     |      2018   | 10       |      5      |
```

Can someone guide me in modifying the above mentioned query. Thanks

Comment: year_name is an interesting concept. Anyway, consider handling issues of data display such as this in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a table of the last three months and then `LEFT JOIN` that to your work orders table (using the month of the work order) to get the results you want. The table of the last 3 months can be generated using a `UNION`:

```
SELECT NOW() AS month
UNION
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
UNION
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

Output (as of 2018-12-07):

```
month
2018-12-07 11:06:15
2018-11-07 11:06:15
2018-10-07 11:06:15
```

Note that it is OK to subtract 1 month from the date as if the day number is larger than the number of days in the previous month it will be adjusted downward to make the date valid (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)).

The final query then becomes:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(m.month) AS month_name, YEAR(m.month) AS year_name, 
       MONTH(m.month) AS month_no, COUNT(wo.Wo_id) work_orders 
FROM (SELECT NOW() AS month
      UNION
      SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      UNION
      SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) m
LEFT JOIN work_orders wo ON MONTH(wo.updated_at) = MONTH(m.month) AND
                            YEAR(wo.updated_at)  = YEAR(m.month)
GROUP by m.month, year_name
ORDER BY m.month DESC
```

Note that we don't need a `WHERE` clause as the values in the `month` table restrict the data to the last 3 months that we are interested in. Also we use a `LEFT JOIN` so that we get a result for each month even if there were no work orders that month.

Output:

```
month_name  year_name   month_no    work_orders
December    2018        12          3
November    2018        11          0
October     2018        10          5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17b3663b1d817f0fc2970e9c5356c988)

Comment: Perfect answer to my problem. Thanks

Just a quick query. What if I need the data of last 6 or 9 months. On Performance point of view Is it fine to write multiple `UNION SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH` ?

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza for just the 12 months it should be fine. If you wanted to do it by weeks or days it would probably make more sense to build a calendar table in your database and `JOIN` to that instead.